# Encryption exception: you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)

Tags: java, encryption, tripledes

error: Encryption exception: you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine

I have read that to resolve this, one must download the local_policy, US_export_policy jars and put it in jre\lib\security folder which I did. I even overwritten the ones that are already existing. But the error is still showing. I restart VMware, redeployed app, republished, clean but did not help. It does not have dependencies as one have suggested somewhere as my java se is 1.7 version.

Any suggestion that might help me resole this other than the ones I already tried?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple JREs installed? It really is that simple to install the JCE, so make sure to double check all "simple" mistakes first.

Comment: check permissions and ownership of downloaded files...